# Efficiency in swapping array elements vs Array indices

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, compare-and-swap

I have a quick question: I know that the complexity of both snippets is same. Yet, I want to know which one is comparatively better and why? This is the selection sort code:

This is what I wrote:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j <= n - 1; j++) 
                {
                    if (a[j] < a[i]) 
                    {
                        int temp = a[i];
                        a[i] = a[j];
                        a[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is what my friend wrote:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                int iMin = i; 
                for (int j = i + 1; j <= n - 1; j++) 
                {
                    if (a[j] < a[i]) 
                    {
                        iMin = j;
                    }
                    int temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[iMin];
                    a[iMin] = temp;
                }
            }
```

Comment: If you have two horses, and you want to know why one is faster, why don't you race the horses yourself? Why do you ask us to tell you which is faster?

Comment: This isn't about which is faster. I didn't ask him yet but I am just trying to understand if there is a logical explanation to not swap elements directly within the block. Is it just good programming technique or is it about efficiency?

Comment: It may not make much actual difference, but the first is clearly better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is slightly faster because you make swaps only when `a[j] < a[i]`, whereas your friend's code is always making a swap. So, in most cases, your code will make less swaps.

The complexity of both codes are indeed the same, but your "constants" are smaller, so your code is faster.